# ASP.NET use Ajax to add scrollbar to the picture

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I need to add a scroll to "one" picture and load it asynchronously.. with the help of scroll bar...

The picture is bigger than the div area so need to scroll. I can use "overflow: scroll " but it loads the whole picture whereas my requirement is to load the picture as a user moves the scrollbar.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The would help to load a page with multiple large images in the manner you are describing

[Lazy Load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

It isn't built for one giant sized image which is what you want. However it should be an easy matter to slice you image into reason sized regions or tiles and use this loader.

Out of interest really - here is a utility that will [automatically slice up images](http://supersimple.org/imagetiles) to protect them from theft. I occurs to me that you could combine the two if you didn't fancy manually splitting the image - or just wanted to be a bit of a coding hero. In any case the link shows that sliced and recombined images look perfectly fine. Users can't tell if it's done right.